# Scroll bar on <asp:CheckBoxList>?

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone help me to put a vertical scroll bar for an `<asp:CheckBoxList>`?

Answer (score 1):

http://bytes.com/forum/thread298532.html

Answer (score 1):

i tried like this

`<div style="height:100px;overflow:auto;">
   <asp:CheckBoxList></asp:CheckBoxList>
</div>`

and it worked out..!! 
Thanks a lot.! :)

Comment: Unfortunately with AutoPostBack turned on, it scrolls back up to the top of the list every time the user changes the selection.

Comment: You could try turning off AutoPostBack and make it do an ajax call back to the server instead?